# How to have static folders within a Visual Studio ProjectGroup .vstemplate?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

My ProjectGroup template contains 2 projects. At the same level as the projects I need a folder (with sub folders and files) to be created. The folder names and contents are static.

My template looks like this

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">

  <TemplateData>
   <Name>My Solution</Name>
   ...
  </TemplateData>

  <TemplateContent>

    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyCPPProject">
        Folder1\MyCPP.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyCSharpProject">
        Folder1\MyCSharp.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>

    <!-- * * * *  Below is my attempt to create the folders  * * * * -->

    <Folder Name="packages" TargetFolderName="packages">
      <Folder Name="debug" TargetFolderName="debug">
        <Folder Name="bin" TargetFolderName="bin">
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="doc" TargetFolderName="doc">
          <Folder Name="text" TargetFolderName="text">
            <Folder Name="abc" TargetFolderName="abc">
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false"     TargetFileName="file1.xml">file1.xml</ProjectItem>
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="file2.xml">file2.xml</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
            <Folder Name="def" TargetFolderName="def">
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="image.png">image.png</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
          </Folder>
        </Folder>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </TemplateContent>

  <WizardExtension>
   ...
  </WizardExtension>

</VSTemplate>
```

Here's a picture

[image]

I tried using Folder elements within the ProjectGroup. This does not work (but also does not cause errors).

Can this be done with .vstemplate? Or do I need to use a WizardExtension (and C# code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a [WizardExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/extensibility/wizardextension-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2015)

So in summary

1. Add the required files as part of one of the project templates (make changes to both the .vstemplate **AND** .csproj / .cxproj files).
2. After the project is installed, inside the `RunFinished` method of the wizard extension move the files to the required location.
3. In the `ProjectFinishedGenerating` method of the wizard extension use the [EnvDTE Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2015) object to remove the files from the project.

Below some code to make that more concret.

**1**

Add the folders + files to the project template [.vstemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/extensibility/vstemplate-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2015) (not to the project group template shown in the question) and to the .csproj / cxproj file. This is a temporary measure so that when the user executes the project template in Visual Studio (by pressing File -> New Project), the files are initially installed / created.

Below is the .vstemplate file

```
...
<Folder Name="packages" TargetFolderName="packages">
      <Folder Name="debug" TargetFolderName="debug">
        <Folder Name="doc" TargetFolderName="doc">
          <Folder Name="text" TargetFolderName="text">
            <Folder Name="abc" TargetFolderName="abc">
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false"     TargetFileName="file1.xml">file1.xml</ProjectItem>
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="file2.xml">file2.xml</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
            <Folder Name="def" TargetFolderName="def">
              <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="image.png">image.png</ProjectItem>
            </Folder>
          </Folder>
        </Folder>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
...
```

And here an extract from the .cxproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
 <ItemGroup Label="RTMaps Documentation">
    <None Include ="packages\debug\doc\text\abc\file1.xml" />
    <None Include ="packages\debug\doc\text\abc\file2.xml" />
    <None Include ="packages\debug\doc\text\def\image.png" />
 </ItemGroup>
...
</Project>
```

**2**

In the WizardExtension use System.IO to move the folders (and their contents), e.g.

```
public void RunFinished()
    { 
        try
        {
            var src = Path.Combine(_destinationDirectory, "packages");
            var dest = Path.Combine(_solutionDirectory, "admin");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
            dest = Path.Combine(dest, "packages");
            Directory.Move(src, dest);
        }
        catch
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

I get the `_destinationDirectory` and `_solutionDirectory` during the `RunStarted` method.

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {           
        _destinationDirectory = replacementsDictionary["$destinationdirectory$"];
        _solutionDirectory = replacementsDictionary["$solutiondirectory$"];
    }
```

**3**

Finally tidy up the project (.csproj or .cxproj file) programmatically using the [EnvDTE Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project?view=visualstudiosdk-2015) object. Only the files need to be removed.

```
 public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
    {        
        try
        {
            project.ProjectItems.Item("file1.xml").Remove();
            project.ProjectItems.Item("file2.xml").Remove();
            project.ProjectItems.Item("image.png").Remove();
        }
        catch
        {
           ....
        }
    }
```